# Can Google IAM or IBM IAM be used as an authentication service by an external microservice?

Tags: authentication, microservices, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a requirement where I need to develop a microservice and secure the service using an enterprise IAM solution.

But I am very much confused now if at all IAM will solve my purpose or not.

As I have understood going through various articles, that IAM is for authorizing cloud resources.

But I need to authorize a user to allow accessing the external microservice api.
What do I need here for the solution? Is IAM alone sufficient for the authentication purpose?
If not please suggest in brief what I should look for.

Any hints on the Google cloud or IBM cloud will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Google Oauth for this problem. I also believe IAM won't solve your problem.